# TypeError: statevalue is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am making a comments component wherein I get data from a local stored json file. I import the data in the variable **data** and set its corresponding fields to my state values. But when I pass the data through the context, it says that it is undefined.

*data.json*

```
{
  "currentUser": {
    "image": { 
      "png": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png",
      "webp": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.webp"
    },
    "username": "juliusomo"
  },
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "content": "Impressive! Though it seems the drag feature could be improved. But overall it looks incredible. You've nailed the design and the responsiveness at various breakpoints works really well.",
      "createdAt": "1 month ago",
      "score": 12,
      "user": {
        "image": { 
          "png": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.png",
          "webp": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.webp"
        },
        "username": "amyrobson"
      },
      "replies": []
    }
  ]
}
```

this is how I store and pass data
*context.js*

```
import data from "./data";

const AppContext = React.createContext();

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { comments, setComments } = useState(data.comments);
  const { currUser, setCurrUser } = useState(data.currentUser);
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ comments, currUser }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

this is where I get the error
*App.js*

```
import { useGlobalContext } from "./context";
const App = () => {
  const { comments, currUser } = useGlobalContext();
  ...
}
```

[this is the error exactly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuwUR.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useState` hook returns an array, not an object. Array destructuring assignment is used. First element is the state value, the second is the state updater function.

[React.useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

```
const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [comments, setComments] = useState(data.comments);
  const [currUser, setCurrUser] = useState(data.currentUser);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ comments, currUser }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```